# WebDriver wait for iframe, identify by part of its name

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem on waiting for an iframe and switching to it when I know only part of its name. The name is unique every time the page is loaded. The pattern is "Framexxxxxxx" where "xxxxx" are random numbers.

Is there any way to make webdriver ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt() to find that iframe?

So far I've tried:

```
By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(name(),'Frame')]")
By.xpath("iframe[starts-with(@name,'Frame')]")
```

and some other ways - no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with below locators

```
By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@name,'Frame')]")
By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name,'Frame')]")
By.cssSelector("iframe[name*='Frame']")
```

You can use same locators to wait for the iframe to appear/available.

Answer (score 0):

Use CssSelector to identify iframe.. if there is only one iframe better i think it is better to use this..

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe")));
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some issue to wait iframe for loading so i tried this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);      
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'Frame')]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- It waits for iframe to load and switch
- It waits for his body to load
- In addition wait more 3 seconds for full rendering